# What permissions are needed to edit Elementor Hello templates in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, permissions, elementor

I would like to allow non-admins to edit templates.
As an administrator, I still have the "edit with elementor" option there:
[Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj3Qa.png)

I have installed the User-Roll-Editor and assigned the following permissions:
[Permissions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHmdT.png)

These permissions don't seem to be enough.

Comment: WordPress, theme and plugins are on the latest versions

Answer (score 0):

This is an built-in feature of Elementor. This means that you are not need an thirdy-party plugin or addition to achieve your goal.

Please, give some minutes and read the guide here:

Follow the link to [Elementor Role Manager](https://elementor.com/blog/wordpress-user-roles-elementor-role-manager/)

Having fun! ;)

Comment: With this featue I only have the possibility to limit the permission of the role. But this is exactly the opposite of what I want to reach. 

Neither "No access to the editor" nor "Access only to edit content" allows a role to edit the templates.